# For which host should an SSL private key be issued on a balanced, clustered IS instance?

Tags: ssl, nginx, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a working WSO2 Identity Server cluster. As these servers are going to manage a lot of traffic, i also set up an nginx balancer and opened the service login endpoint at port 9443.

As the balancer is configured to keep sessions, i added the "ip_hash" argument to the balancer config and restarted the service. The browser is now trowing the following error: "An error occurred during a connection to balancer:9443. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)". Okay, so i must enable SSL for this connection as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/https-load-balancing-nginx) guide. Simple enough... I thought.

My question is... If I need both identity server instances on the cluster to respond, should i assign the same private key to both instances in order to enable both for encrypting and decrypting the traffic? Or should I make a key for the balancer? How should it be set up?

P.S. I don't want the traffic to be sent unencrypted on the internal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By providing ip_hash it will enable session for 1 node. Please enable sticky session to make both nodes work. You can simply then define a upstream and balance to both nodes.